# Pre-Release missing in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I uploaded my application to App Store yesterday. I was waiting for a long time as I couldn't find my binary file in Pre-Release option. I thought it may take some time. But on the sudden the UI of iTunes Connect has been changed today and there is no Build still in the app store. Still the status is Prepare for Submission. What am I supposed to do. Kindly suggest me guys.

Comment: but the build which i uploaded is still missing. I want to know whether i need to submit the app again or is there any procedures?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I had to resubmit my binary file to app store again. May be due to the change in UI. I was uploading last night. I guess after that only the UI might have been changed from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Tap on Activity tab check that your build.